# import txt file into excel not work if File extension is upper letters

Tags: excel, vba

I need help for vba. i had code for import txt file into excel not work if File extension is upper letters

```
If xlsheet.Name = LCase(Replace(fso.GetFileName(txtfile), ".txt", "")) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
If xlsheet.Name = LCase(Replace(fso.GetFileName(txtfile), ".txt", "",1,-1,vbBinaryCompare)) Then
```

Comment: Thanks, that's another way you saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.GetBaseName()` which returns filename without extension

```
If LCase(xlsheet.Name) = LCase(fso.GetBaseName(txtfile)) Then
```

or

```
If StrComp(xlsheet.Name, fso.GetBaseName(txtfile), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
```

Example:

```
Sub ttt()
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    txtfile = "c:\temp\Test.txt"
    If StrComp(xlsheet.Name, fso.GetBaseName(txtfile), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "matched:", xlsheet.Name, fso.GetBaseName(txtfile)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Prints**

```
matched:      TEST          Test
```